# Get child data Microsoft Dynamics WebAPI

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I am using the Microsoft Dynamics CRM WebAPI to access an on Premise version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016.  I have two custom entities `ccseq_ProductEvaluation` and `ccseq_ProductEvaluationArea`.  `ccseq_ProductEvaluation` is the parent of `ccseq_ProductEvaluationArea`.  I am trying to build the url to retrieve the `ccseq_ProductEvaluationArea` records for a specific `ccseq_ProductEvaluation` record.  I have read the [Dynamics API reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLTqW.png), but I have not been able to build the correct url.  Below is the current url I have tried.  What am I missing?

### URL

```
https://mainurl.com/api/data/v8.0/ccseq_productevaluations?$expand=ccseq_productevaluationid
```

### ccseq_ProductEvaluation

[image: Product Evaluation Design]

### ccseq_ProductEvaluationArea

[image: Product Evaluation Area Design]

### 1:N Relationship

[image: Relationship Details]

Comment: use CRM REST Builder from Jason Lattimer to build your query https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder

Comment: @GuidoPreite I was unable to get this project to run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query should read like this:

```
https://mainurl.com/api/data/v8.0/ccseq_productevaluations(915e89f5-29fc-e511-80d2-00155db07c77)?$select=ccseq_productname&$expand=ccseq_ccseq_productevaluation_ccseq_producteval($select=ccseq_evaluationarea)
```

Here the guid should be replaced with the ID of the product evaluation record at hand.